# Python function to take input from two different functions and return a concatenated string

Tags: python, class, oop, return-value, string-concatenation

I have two different classes. I want to create a new class which takes the return value of the functions of each class and concatenates them with a '+' character and returns the value. The return value of these two functions of the classes are of string type. The two classes are as follows:

```
import csv
import re


class Drug_Product():
    def drug_product(content):
        with open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\drug_product(s).csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
            reader = csv.reader(myFile)
            for row in reader:
                v = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[0]) + r'\b', content, re.IGNORECASE)
                if v: 
                    return(v.group(0))
                    break




class Product:
    def product_matcher(content):

        with open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\EV_codes_sheet.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
            reader = csv.reader(myFile)
            for row in reader:
                if len(row[1])>=4:
                    v = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[1]) + r'\b', content, re.IGNORECASE)
                    if v: 
                        return(v.group(0))
                        break
```

So if pass a 'content', the first function returns 'tablet' and the second function return 'ethanol'. I want the value as 'tablet + ethanol'. How do I have one function which runs these two functions together and returns the concatenated string. Presently I am running the two scripts separately to get the output from each. Any help on this will be really useful

Comment: `'{}+{}'.format(Drug_Product.drug_product(content), Product.product_matcher(content))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
   return f"{Product.product_matcher(content)} + {Drug_Product.drug_product(content)}"
```